# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (299,491) (299,491,3). How to solve this in pixelwise multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

An RGB image(Img1) of size 299x491 is converted to its inverted binary(Imag2).  I want to do pixel-wise multiplication of Img1 and Img2. Now when I do Img1 @ Img2 I get undesirable output.
Again when I tried with np.multiply(Img2, Img1)

```
 import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('example1.png')
h = np.size(img1, 0)
w = np.size(img1, 1)
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
            grayImage[i, j, ] = 1 if grayImage[i, j, ] >= 127 else 0

grayImage = grayImage -1
cv2.imshow('img',  grayImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)          
cv2.imshow('img', img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
img = np.multiply(grayImage,img)
#img = img1 @ grayImage 
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Value error:  operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (299,491) (299,491,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.):

```
Img1 * Img2[...,None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the gray image to color in Python/OpenCV

```
gray3 = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

or

```
gray3 = cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])
```